# Wordpress 500 Server Error After Database Uploaded

Tags: wordpress, server-error

I'm working on uploading a Wordpress website to a client's hosting account. I have it running on a live server where I can show my clients the work that I've done. While moving it to their server, I get the following error on the front end of the site:

> Server Error 500
>   The website encountered an error while retrieving http://websitehere.net. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

The steps I've taken are the following:

1. Tried a fresh install of Wordpress, which worked. A blank install works perfectly. When I uploaded my exported database, the error occurred.
2. Checked error log, but the log shows no errors. The page is literally blank.
3. Tried disabling all plugins. Error still persists.
4. Tried installing on another one of my hosts and that works.

Not sure what to do here. The client wants the site on their hosting account, as they should.

Comment: It *could* be a problem with shared hosting (I'm assuming this is what your client is using?)

Comment: @OliverQueen It could be but I contacted the host this morning and they've told me that it's a "design/development issue" and that someone else had issues and it was resolved on the user's side, not the host.

Comment: Have you tried `Increasing the PHP Memory Limit`?

Comment: @OliverQueen, yes. I have increased to 96Ms.

Comment: Try renaming your .htaccess to something out and see if the .htaccess is giving you problems.

Comment: @OliverQueen, did that too. No luck.

Comment: Well I'm useless as I'm not physically on the server. I'll just add this to my long list of reasons why I dislike wordpress.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: are you using this syntax (short tags) - <?=$var ?>

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs?

Comment: @TomMillard, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @VasimVanzara. Yes. There are no errors. The error log is blank.

Comment: Can we move in chat room?

Comment: @VasimVanzara, sure. Not sure  how to go about that, but let me know.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log? You should see some information about the 500 error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four Possible stage we can do:

**- Checking for Corrupt .htaccess File** 
   Rename .htaccess and load site.It create own file if its not there.

**-Increasing the PHP Memory Limit**
   Sometimes this error can happen if you are exhausting your PHP memory limit.

**-Deactivate all Plugins**
  deactive from admin if you do so otherwise rename pluginfolder and create new blank plugin folder.

-**Re-uploading Core Files**

If the plugin option didn’t fix the internal server error, then it is worth re-uploading the wp-admin and wp-includes folder from a fresh WordPress install. This will NOT remove any of your information, but it may solve the problem in case any file was corrupted.

Comment: Thanks Vasim. I've tried all that and none of it works.

Comment: go to your root directory

Comment: can you access your admin

Comment: Yes. Trying to open the log now.

Comment: [08-Feb-2016 16:47:40] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /home3/funding/public_html/fundingsite/wp-content/themes/startit/framework/lib/qode.layout.inc on line 2850

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102925/discussion-between-vasim-vanzara-and-petey).